# Can't delete exited Init Container

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I'm using Kubernetes 1.15.7 and my issue is similar to https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/62362

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: init-demo
spec:
  containers:
  - name: nginx
    image: nginx
    ports:
    - containerPort: 80
    volumeMounts:
    - name: workdir
      mountPath: /usr/share/nginx/html
 # These containers are run during pod initialization
 restartPolicy: Always
 initContainers:
 - name: install
   image: busybox
   command:
   - sh
   - -c
   - sleep 60
   volumeMounts:
   - name: workdir
     mountPath: "/work-dir"
 dnsPolicy: Default
 volumes:
 - name: workdir
   emptyDir: {}
```

On the node the container is runner if I issue a `docker container prune` ,it removes the exited busybox (init) container. Only to restart it again and trigger the pod to restart too.

I found the github issue similar to this but without much explaination. These exited container as such do not show up to consumer much same using `docker system df` but it doesnt allow me to run the prune command as a whole on the node.

Comment: What's your higher-level goal; why are you directly and manually running `docker` commands on your Kubernetes nodes?

Comment: This is part of the clean up script that has to run on all the nodes to clear the exited containers. But I cannot just delete all exited ones as few are init containers among them.

Answer (score 0):

Kubelet manages garbage collection of docker images so you dont have to.
Take a look at [k8s documentation for more info on this topic](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/kubelet-garbage-collection/).

From k8s documentation:

> Garbage collection is a helpful function of kubelet that will clean up unused images and unused containers. Kubelet will perform garbage collection for containers every minute and garbage collection for images every five minutes.
>
> **External garbage collection tools are not recommended as these tools can potentially break the behavior of kubelet by removing containers expected to exist**